# Destructuring this.props into Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In this sample code below: It is `React` and `Next.js`

```
import App, { Container} from "next/app";
import React from "react";

class MyApp extends App{
    render() {
        const { Component } = this.props;
        return (
            <Container>
                <p>Hey I am on every page</p>
                <Component/>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default MyApp;
```

My question is about this line:

```
const { Component } = this.props;
```

My questions:
How is this working? This is the highest page level I have. So who is passing `this.props` to it?
Also what kind of syntax is that? Why it called `Components`? Could he call it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MyApp` component extends a component named [App](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/pages/_app.tsx), which is an internal Next react component. The reason you'd want to extend `App` is if you're calling `getInitialProps` **before** each page is loaded. You can think of App as a HOC (higher order component) that calls `getInitialProps` in `MyApp` **first**, then other Next methods within a page, like: `getInitialProps`, `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps`, `getStaticPaths` **second**.

This creates a render-blocking scenario where `MyApp.getInitialProps` can block page-level methods from being executed until it has been resolved.

In your case, you don't even need to extend App since you're not calling getInitialProps, and instead, you can just use a pure function (or remove `_app.js` completely if you don't need to include metadata or wrap each `page` with some sort of layout component):

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

All subsequent `pages` (like `/pages/example.js`) will be passed to this `MyApp` component as the named `Component` prop while any props returned from one the methods mentioned above will be passed to MyApp as the named `pageProps` prop.

You can *kind of* think of `App` (next/app) like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MyApp from "../_app.js"; // custom _app page
import Example from "../example.js"; // a page component

class App extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const { pageProps } = await MyApp.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { pageProps }; // this.props.pageProps
  };

  render() {
    return <MyApp Component={Example} pageProps={this.props.pageProps} />
  }
}
```

--

On a side note, the `Container` component has been [deprecated](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/8327) since v9.0.4

Answer (score 0):

The `Component` prop is the active page, so whenever you navigate between routes, `Component` will change to the new page. Therefore, any `props` you send to `Component` will be received by the page.